# How can I add submenu to this responsive menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, navigation

I have this responsive navigation.But I can't add multilevel sub Menu to this navigation.
How can I add multilevel sub Menu to this 
[`responsive navigation link`](http://jsfiddle.net/goldfingerxyz/hh16upps/)

Comment: I saw your **sample link**. When you want the **sub menu** to show? Is it when **hovered** or **click**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have made some changes

I have updated the fiddle SubItems are also toggling.

Note: CSS changes have to be made , working on functionality

> FOR DESKTOP

you can write following script
**whatever width you desire**

```
 if($(window).width()>"760")  {
    $("ul.main li").on("click",function(){
       if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {  if($(this).hasClass("subOpen")){  
         $(this).removeClass("subOpen");
         $(this).find("ul.submenu").hide(300);
       }
       else {                                                 
       $(this).addClass("subOpen");
       $(this).find("ul.submenu").show(300);
       }
                                                       }
       });
    }
```

> MOBILE VERSION

```
//MENU TOGGLE FUNCTION
     $('.rmm-button').click(function(){
            // $('.rmm-toggled, .rmm-toggled .rmm-button').click(function(){
                if ( $(this).is(".rmm-closed")) {
                    alert($(this).parent().parent().html());
                     $(this).parent().parent().find("ul.main").show(300);
                     $(this).removeClass("rmm-closed");
                }
                else {
                    alert($(this).html());
                    $(this).find('ul').stop().hide(300);
                     $(this).addClass("rmm-closed");
                }

            }); 

//SUBMENU TOGGLE FUNCTION
  $(".rmm-toggled ul li").on("click",function(){
     if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {
           if($(this).hasClass("subOpen")){
           $(this).removeClass("subOpen");
           $(this).find("ul.submenu").hide(300);
         }
         else{
         $(this).addClass("subOpen");
         $(this).find("ul.submenu").show(300);
         }


     }
```

[**Here's Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/hh16upps/5/)

Comment: yes this is great and working fine in mobile view 
http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/hh16upps/2/
But this not working (sub menu is not showing) desktop view resolution like 1024px

Comment: @SubhajitPanja Updated the answer .. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

I think you used http://responsivemobilemenu.com/en/. It still not suppose to have that feature yet. They clearly note down in their site. With some serious code hack may can give a solution to you. Otherwise there are plenty of good plugins to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: If you want help further let me know!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a submenu, place a new `ul` tag inside the `li`:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href='#about-me'>About me</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href='#'>SubItem</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then with some CSS and JS code you can create a nice responsive menu.

**CSS**

```
.submenu {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.menu > li').hover(function() {
   // Show submenu
   $(this).find('> ul.submenu').show();
}, function() {
   // Hide submenu
   $(this).find('> ul.submenu').hide();
});
```

Comment: I applied this way but can't work 
Please see the below link 
http://jsfiddle.net/goldfingerxyz/8m2c39uy/

Comment: You didn't include your js in your jsfiddle